# Sum of digits in a subset of a set

Tags: java, optimization, powerset

I have a set *S* like this `[00 01 10 11]` and an element *E* as `11`. I want to find out the number of subsets of this set whose sum of digits is greater than or equal to the sum of digits of the element *E*.

For example in this case the answer is 10.
The 10 sets satisfying the constraints are :

```
00 01 10 11 // Sum is 3 which is greater than 2 (sum of digits of E)
00 01 11 
00 10 11
01 10 11
00 11
01 11
10 11
11
00 01 10
01 10
```

The sum of all the digits of the above subsets is greater than or equal to 2 (sum of digits of *E*).

I tried the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> inputSet = new HashSet<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    int M = sc.nextInt();// specifies the length of the digts in the set.
    for (long i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
        inputSet.add(sc.next());
    }
    long sum = 0;
    String E = sc.next();//
    sc.close();
    for (String str : E.split("(?!^)")) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    List<Set<String>> subSets = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
    for (String addToSets : inputSet) {
        List<Set<String>> newSets = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
        for (Set<String> curSet : subSets) {
            Set<String> copyPlusNew = new HashSet<String>();
            copyPlusNew.addAll(curSet);
            copyPlusNew.add(addToSets);
            newSets.add(copyPlusNew);
        }
        Set<String> newValSet = new HashSet<String>();
        newValSet.add(addToSets);
        newSets.add(newValSet);
        subSets.addAll(newSets);
    }
    long sum1;
    long count = 0;
    for (Set<String> set : subSets) {
        sum1 = 0;
        for (String setEntry : set) {
            for (String s : setEntry.split("(?!^)")){
                sum1 = sum1 + Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
        }
        if (sum == sum1 || sum1 > sum)
            count = count+1;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Constraints
1 <= N <= 10^5

1 <= M <= 20

The above approach won't work for the size of sets of the range 10<sup>5</sup>. Please help providing an efficient approach for this.
Thanks!

Comment: IS the Element E in your set as last value? (Trying to understand the example on line 1 of your post)

Comment: "Won't work." Does that mean it runs out of memory? Or does it run too slow?

Comment: I'm thinking an easier approach is total number of subsets minus the ones that are less than the digits of E... so 2^|set| - (numSubsetslessthandigitsE)

Comment: @Adam total number of subsets is 2^(size of set)

Comment: @pvg. I know. My comment wasn't done.

Comment: Are 1 and 0 the only allowed digits in the set? Are all elements two digits long?

Comment: @Ivan It runs way too slow.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen The 9th line of my code is the element E.

Comment: @adam then you can see how that approach can't answer the question - 2^10000 is more subsets than elementary particles in the universe, by many orders of magnitude

Comment: @pvg Yes only 1 and 0 are the digits allowed. No, the all the elements are not two digit long. They can be long upto 20 digits. I have edited my code. The variable M specifies the length of the digit.

Comment: @g19 maybe you should just post the homework question, since this sounds like homework? Hard to answer if you miss key constraints. It's clearly about finding a solution that does not involve trying to produce every conceivable subset and this depends very closely on how the original set is defined.

Comment: @pvg I have added the constraints. Please check if this makes sense to you :)

Comment: What are N and M in relation to S and E?

Comment: @Ivan From the code it seems N is the size of the set S and M is length of the digits of the set S. E is element with which the comparison needs to be made. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I doubt he's going to have 2^10000 subsets. Be real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch in solving this question is just remembering that `addition is associative`. So when you add those digits does not really matter. So if we reduce this to a known problem, it's easy to solve this.

Convert your input array to `sum of digits array`. That is if your original array is A, then the relation with your resulting array B will be:

```
          B[i] = sum of digits of(A[i]).
```

Say K is `sum of digits(E)`

Then your problem reduces to

```
     Find number of subsets in B whose sum is <= K
```

Which is easy.

**EDIT:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A ={01,11,111};
    int B[] = new int[A.length];
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        B[i]=getDigitSum(A[i]);
    }
     int E = 11;
    int K= getDigitSum(E);
    int N =B.length;
    Arrays.sort(B);
    int DP[][] = new int[B.length][B[B.length-1]+1];


    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        DP[i][B[i]] = 1;

        if (i == 0) continue;

        for (int k=0;k<K;k++) {
            DP[i][k] += DP[i - 1][k];
        }
        for (int k=0;k<K;k++) {
            if( k + B[i] >= K) break ;
            DP[i][k + B[i]] += DP[i - 1][k];
        }
    }
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<K;i++) {
        sum = sum +DP[N-1][i];
    }
    int result = ((int)Math.pow(2,N)) - sum-1;
    System.out.println(result);

}

private static int getDigitSum(int num) {
    int sum =0;
    while(num >0){
       sum=sum+ (num%10);
        num= num/10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me some pseudocode or code ? It'll be easier to understand then. Not getting the link part.

Comment: @g19 I have updated the answer, Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Lemme try! Converting the solution to java.

Comment: Not working :( Wrong output. The output is 15 for the sample case but it should be 10.

Comment: 4 2  
00  
10  
01  
11  
11

Comment: Can you please help me translate it in java or help me with the same.

Comment: @g19  try this code, I have tested it with few test cases. It works.